# Pagination on php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I want to divide my data to pages.
And I think I am almost there except a little mildly problem.

My output on first page which is excellent:

[image: good result]

My output on other pages which is where the problem is occurring:

[image: bad result]

Other pages doen't look nice. My code is below, I would really appreciate if someone wants to help.

```
    <?php
$per_page = 1; //limit
if(intval(@$_GET['page']))
{
$page = intval(@$_GET['page']);
}else{
$page= 0;
}
$id =   $_GET['id'];
$data2=mysql_query("select id from files where cat=".$_GET['id']."");
$data=mysql_num_rows($girdi2);
$toplam=ceil($data/$per_page);
$r_now = $page * $sayfa_basina;
$f_data = mysql_query("select * from files where cat=".$_GET['id']." order by id desc limit $r_now, $per_page");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($f_data)) {

echo "<td><a href='file.php?id=$r[id]'><b>$r[title]</b></a></td>";
 }

####Pagination####
for ($i = 0; $i <= $toplam-1; $i++)
{
if(!$page != $i) { printf('<a href="?id='.$id.'&page=%d"><b>%d</b></a> ', $i, $i+1); }  
else { printf('<a href="?id='.$id.'&page=%d">[%d]</a> ', $i, $i+1); }
} ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `$_GET['id']` in your query, use `$page` which should be an integer.. What is `GET['page']` and `$i` on the subsequent pages?

Comment: It looks like the styling is inversed. Like `bold` for current page and `brackets` for other pages when you're on the first page, and then the other way around for other pages. Maybe there is an error in your condition. You could try `if($page == $i)` instead of `if(!$page != $i)`. It won't solve the issue, but it's easier to read

Comment: @Hakim, actually it solved the whole issue. :) Thanks a lot.